# Load Windows form after complete combobox data load in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, combobox, async-await

I have a `form` for employees called frmEmployees where I need to load couple of `combo box` with data like country, category, nationality, such others.

Now when user click on to open frmEmployees, window is stuck for bit and then open. I assume that this is because of data loading and initializing the `combo box`.
Now! what I want is, just after click on button to open frmEmployees run a progress bar till data loading complete and then open form.

```
public frmEmployee()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        con = new Connection();

        LoadComboboxDS();
    }
```

I have tried also

```
private void FrmEmployee_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadComboboxDS();
    }



private void LoadComboboxDS()
    {
        //company
        var _companies = con.Companies.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
        _companies.Insert(0,new data.Models.CompanyModels.Company { Address = new data.Models.Address(), Code = null, Name = "--Select--", BaseCurrency = new data.Models.Currency() });
        cbCompany.DataSource = _companies;
        cbCompany.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cbCompany.ValueMember = "ID";

        //gender
        cbGender.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender));

        //merital status
        cbMeritalStatus.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MaritalStatus));

        //citizenship
        var _citizenships = con.Countries.Select(x => x.Citizenship).Distinct().ToList();
        _citizenships.Insert(0, "--Select--");
        cbCitizenship.DataSource = _citizenships;
        cbCitizenship.DisplayMember = "Citizenship";

        //nationality
        var _nations = con.Countries.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().ToList();
        _nations.Insert(0, "--Select--");
        cbNationality.DataSource = _nations;
        cbNationality.DisplayMember = "Name";

        //domicile
        var _domiciles = con.Countries.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().ToList();
        _domiciles.Insert(0, "--Select--");
        cbDomicile.DataSource = _domiciles;
        cbDomicile.DisplayMember = "Name";

        //cast category
        var _casts = con.CastCategories.Select(x => new {x.ShortText, x.Description}).Distinct().ToList();
        _casts.Insert(0, new { ShortText = "", Description = "--Select--" });
        cbCategory.DataSource = _casts;
        cbCategory.DisplayMember = "Description";
        cbCategory.ValueMember = "ShortText";

        //religion 
        cbReligion.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Religion));

    }
```

Comment: You should use a backgroundworker for the progress bar.An easier way is to simply change the Cursor Icon to a loading symbol.

Comment: Can you suggest any sample code. Because I have tried some but no luck

Comment: @kurdy Backgroundworker will not work for UI elements. The UI controls needs to be loaded in the UI thread.

Comment: thats right @Harsh

Comment: What ORM do you use?

Comment: Entity Framework @YeldarKurmangaliyev

Comment: @Siraj Why don't you use `ToListAsync` in combination with `async`, `await` and `Task` return type ?

Comment: @Harsh I already implemented a progressbar which is controlled by a backgroundworker in Winforms. You simply have to run the worker async and call the ProgressChangedEvent from it.. worked flawless

Comment: @kurdy You are right. Progress bar is not the issue here. But loading the comboboxes is something which cannot be done through BG Workers.

Comment: @Harsh now I get it. Next time I will explain my idea less vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See what I have done... if anyone can review my code it would be appreciable.

```
public class EmployeeFormDataRepesenter
{
    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public List<CastCategory> CastCategories { get; set; }
}

public void LoadData(EmployeeFormDataRepesenter representer)
    {

        //gender
        cbGender.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender));
        //merital status
        cbMeritalStatus.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MaritalStatus));
        //religion 
        cbReligion.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Religion));

        //company
        var _companies = representer.Companies;
        _companies.Insert(0, new data.Models.CompanyModels.Company { Address = new data.Models.Address(), Code = null, Name = "--Select--", BaseCurrency = new data.Models.Currency() });
        cbCompany.DataSource = _companies;
        cbCompany.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cbCompany.ValueMember = "ID";

        //citizenship
        var _citizenships = representer.Countries.Select(x => x.Citizenship).ToList();
        _citizenships.Insert(0, "--Select--");
        cbCitizenship.DataSource = _citizenships;
        cbCitizenship.DisplayMember = "Citizenship";

        //nationality
        var _nations = representer.Countries.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
        _nations.Insert(0, "--Select--");
        cbNationality.DataSource = _nations;
        cbNationality.DisplayMember = "Name";

        //domicile
        var _domiciles = representer.Countries.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
        _domiciles.Insert(0, "--Select--");
        cbDomicile.DataSource = _domiciles;
        cbDomicile.DisplayMember = "Name";

        //cast category
        var _casts = representer.CastCategories.Select(x => new { x.ShortText, x.Description }).Distinct().ToList();
        _casts.Insert(0, new { ShortText = "", Description = "--Select--" });
        cbCategory.DataSource = _casts;
        cbCategory.DisplayMember = "Description";
        cbCategory.ValueMember = "ShortText";
    }




private async void btnEmplyee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new Connection();
        Action showProgress = () => frmStatrup._progressBar.Visible = true;
        Action hideProgress = () => frmStatrup._progressBar.Visible = false;

        EmployeeFormDataRepesenter representer;

        Task<List<Company>> _taskCompany = new Task<List<Company>>(() =>
        {
            BeginInvoke(showProgress);
            var list = con.Companies.ToListAsync();
            BeginInvoke(hideProgress);
            if (list != null)
                return list.Result;
            return null;
        });

        Task<List<Country>> _taskCountry = new Task<List<Country>>(() =>
        {
            BeginInvoke(showProgress);
            var list = con.Countries.ToListAsync();
            BeginInvoke(hideProgress);
            if (list != null)
                return list.Result;
            return null;
        });

        Task<List<CastCategory>> _taskCasts = new Task<List<CastCategory>>(() =>
        {
            BeginInvoke(showProgress);
            var list = con.CastCategories.ToListAsync();
            BeginInvoke(hideProgress);
            if (list != null)
                return list.Result;
            return null;
        });


        _taskCompany.Start();
        var _companies = await _taskCompany;

        _taskCountry.Start();
        var _countries = await _taskCountry;

        _taskCasts.Start();
        var _casts = await _taskCasts;


        if (_companies.Count != 0)
        {
            representer = new EmployeeFormDataRepesenter();
            representer.Companies = _companies;
            representer.Countries = _countries;
            representer.CastCategories = _casts;
        }
        else
        {
            representer = null;
        }

        if (representer != null)
        {
            frmEmployee _emp = new frmEmployee();
            _emp.LoadData(representer);
            Functions.OpenForm(_emp, this.ParentForm);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Async extension methods of Entity Framework 6 to make your code asynchronous.

Separate your data access and presentation layer, at first:

```
public static class MyRepository // consider not static, just an example
{
    public static async Task<List<Company>> GetCompanies()
    {
        using (var connection = new Connection()) // consider factory
        {
            return await con.Companies.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToListAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<Citizenship>> GetCitizenships()
    {
        using (var connection = new Connection()) // factory?
        {
            return await con.Countries.Select(x => x.Citizenship).Distinct().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can run all these tasks at once and wait for them to complete:

```
// Wherever you are going to open frmEmployee
public async Task openFrmEmployee_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var getCompaniesTask = MyRepository.GetCompanies();
    var getCitizenshipsTask = MyRepository.GetCitizenships();

    await Task.WhenAll(getCompaniesTask, getCitizenshipsTask); // UI thread is not blocked

    var form = new FrmEmployee(getCompaniesTask.Result, getCitizenshipsTask.Result); // form is created with data
}
```

Now, you only need to make your form accept complete data in constructor instead of making your form load this data which breaks abstraction:

```
public class FrmEmployees
{
    public FrmEmployees(List<Company> companies, List<Citizenship> citizenships)
    {
        companies.Insert(0,new data.Models.CompanyModels.Company { Address = new data.Models.Address(), Code = null, Name = "--Select--", BaseCurrency = new data.Models.Currency() });
        cbCompany.DataSource = companies;
        cbCompany.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cbCompany.ValueMember = "ID";

        citizenships.Insert(0, "--Select--");
        cbCitizenship.DataSource = _citizenships;
        cbCitizenship.DisplayMember = "Citizenship";

        // etc.
    }
}
```

One important thing: you can get many tasks and many data passed to a form constructor. If all this data is going to be used often togetther, then you would probably want to encapsulate this "get all these things" logic into a single place to remove possible code duplication.